# OneSignal Action Buttons

Tags: java, android, notifications, onesignal

I'm totally new to app development, Java and StackOverflow and this is my first Android app.

I have implemented OneSignal for push notification delivery. I was just trying to add the support for Action buttons in the notifications.

I want my SplashActivity to start if the user touches on the Action button with the ID: posts and want to launch a URL in the web browser if the user touches on the button with ID: app.

So, this is my ApplicationClass.java:

```
package com.ananya.brokenhearts;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
    }

    private class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result)
        {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null)
            {
                customKey = data.optString("customKey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }

            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

            if (result.action.actionID.equals("posts"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationClass.this, SplashActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (result.action.actionID.equals("app"))
            {
                String url = "http://app.brokenhearts.ml/";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, now, the problem is, no matter what Action button I click on, it's just dismissing the notification.

I don't know which other files are needed. So, here goes my AndroidManifest.xml, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ananya.brokenhearts"
    android:installLocation="auto" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:name=".ApplicationClass">

        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE"/>

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Splash">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="brokenhearts.ml"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="brokenhearts.ml"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.brokenhearts.ml"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.brokenhearts.ml"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong. It'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Yes, I had, but, this app's life is long over and I haven't maintained it. I still have the code, but, I guess, OneSignal might have updated stuff, so, I'll add it as an answer, but, don't expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update this post, I'm posting the code I had used to make this work. It might or might not still be relevant.

```
package com.packagename.android;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import org.json.JSONObject;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
            {
                super.onCreate();
                OneSignal.startInit(this).inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler()).unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true).init();
            }
        //The following part handles the notification buttons. It can trigger opening specific activities based on the additional data passed with the notification.
        public class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler
            {
                @Override
                public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result)
                    {
                        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
                        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
                        String activityToBeOpened;
                        String activity;
                        if (data != null)
                            {
                                activityToBeOpened = data.optString("activityToBeOpened", null);
                                if (activityToBeOpened.equals("Update"))
                                    {
                                        Log.i("OneSignal", "customkey set with value: " + activityToBeOpened);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationClass.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                else if (activityToBeOpened.equals("Main"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationClass.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Just to clarify, the data to be replaced according to your custom key name is the word 'Update' in the line: `if (activityToBeOpened.equals("Update"))` and 'Main' in the line `else if (activityToBeOpened.equals("Main"))`. You can also use a switch if you're going to use more conditions, though I won't recommended using more than 2 or 3 action buttons.